# Angular 6 routing from browser's desktop notification click event yields unexpected behavior

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have created a **[test case](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-do9wmk)** to reproduce the issue I am seeing based on [Routing Angular documentation](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#final-code-review) and the [live demo](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/toh-pt5/stackblitz.html) found therein.

The live demo was slightly modified so that browser desktop notifications are requested and a simple notification is shown in `app.component.ts` [browser notification code was pasted from somewhere].

Please take note of the notification's `onclick` handler below. It merely logs to console and navigates to one of app's original routes.

```
notification.onclick = function () {
        console.log('onclick');
        self.router.navigate(['/heroes']);
      };
```

To reproduce the problem make sure to **Open in New Window** and allow the app to show desktop notifications when prompted. A notification will be shown immediately after giving permissions. Upon clicking the notification you will notice that the router navigates to the new URL but nothing gets rendered. The console output shows 'onclick' as expected but no `ngOnInit()`. The `heroes.component.ts` was also modified to output `ngOnInit()` as shown below, but this never happens. If you were to click the `Heroes` button, the `ngOnInit()` would have worked as expected.

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('ngOnInit');
  this.getHeroes();
}
```

After a bit of debugging it turns out that the router navigates as expected, `heroes` component gets instantiated (as the constructor gets called) but the `ngOnInit()` never executes.

It appears as if the `onclick` context of the browser desktop notification somehow screws up Angular's internals. Is this what really happens? Is this some sort of Angular bug?

I have also tried using [ng-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-push) but the same behavior is observed.

In my own full-blown app there is one slight difference in behavior. The `ngOnInit()` does get called eventually but it takes up to 10 seconds after component's constructor executes. The browser seems to sit idle consuming no CPU during the wait period.

I am baffled. Any ideas? How come routing works normally when a button is clicked yet it demonstrates this strange behavior when used from a click handler of a browser's desktop notification?

Please note I have tested in latest Chrome (67.0.3396.87), Firefox (60.0.2) and Edge (all on Windows 10 with latest updates).

Comment: It is working as expected! I could change the values under heroes list and ngOnInit is getting executed perfectly.

Comment: Are you using unmodified example? Are you clicking the browser notification? If so, very strange.

Comment: Also for me your sample works. I tried in Chrome and in Edge on Windows.

Comment: Which browser versions do you have? Also Did you try in an Incognito window also?

Comment: I see the same issue, `ngOninit` is not running after clicking the notification and being routed to `/heros`. FF and Chrome on Windows

Comment: @TarunLalwani I updated the question with exact browser versions. I can reproduce in all 3 browsers with ease. Please note this is NOT about showing desktop notifications but rather about navigating to a route from notification click event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but the method is ran outside the Angular Zone. That is why the url is changing but Angular doesn't detect it so `ngOnInit` is not called. Note that it run when you click the clear message button for example. You can simply fix it by running it in zone:

```
notification.onclick = () => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        console.log('onclick');
        this.router.navigate(['/heroes']);
    });
};

constructor(private router: Router, private zone: NgZone) {

}
```

Comment: Damn! That's it! You hit the nail on the head! I am speechless. SO won't let me award the bonus for another 4 hours, so please be patient! And thanks a lot!

Comment: First time learning about zones. Woow. Worked in my use case too. Thanks.

Comment: really this worked like a magic!, I am very new to zones, I have used this for the first time and it solved the issue for me

Answer (score -1):

The example is working for me as well.

First, try to enable hash in the routes to eliminate routing problems caused by miss-configured web hosts. You can do this in your primary rout config:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: true
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRouting {}
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, you should enable router tracing, hopefully it will help you figuring out where the issue comes from:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: true,
      enableTracing: true
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRouting {}
```

Is your Route/Component loaded lazily or eagerly?

Comment: I don't like the `useHash` and it also changes nothing. If I add `enableTracing` I do get plenty of debug output. What happens is that the URL changes but the page load gets stuck for many seconds. When it finally loads no additional debug output is shown. So unfortunately nothing useful came out of it. As for your questions... did you check my sample? Whatever the default is (lazy/eager) is what the sample is using. Thanks!

Comment: As many other said, the example provided by you is working as expected. The error must be in your project or device.

Comment: You are just wrong. Some people can reproduce it, others can't. So it's not me or my project. Please see the accepted answer.